# How to i add a level in pandas data frame

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, jupyter-notebook, multi-index

Suppose i already have a data frame .

```
                     Masters    Bachelors   Doctorates/PhD  Associates  None
0   Data Analyst    22.190612   54.196302   0.568990    10.099573   12.944523
1   Data Engineer   17.777778   53.703704   0.740741    8.518519    19.259259
2   Data Scientist  39.583333   27.083333   20.833333   4.166667    8.333333
```

I want it to look like this

```
 JOB TITLE       EDUCATION 
                     Masters    Bachelors   Doctorates/PhD  Associates  None
0   Data Analyst    22.190612   54.196302   0.568990    10.099573   12.944523
1   Data Engineer   17.777778   53.703704   0.740741    8.518519    19.259259
2   Data Scientist  39.583333   27.083333   20.833333   4.166667    8.333333
```

Answer (score 0):

Add these lines to your code.

```
 cols = [('JOB TITLE',''), ('EDUCATION','Masters'), ('EDUCATION','Bachelors'),('EDUCATION','Doctorates/PhD'),('EDUCATION','Associates'),('EDUCATION','None')]
 df.columns = pd.MultiIndex.from_tuples(cols)
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want row numbers as `JOB` column. Then in the beginning add:

```
df = pd.concat([pd.Series(np.arange(len(df[''])), index=df.index, name=''), df], axis=1)
```

Later add multi-index column names as shown below

```
cols = [('JOB',''), ('TITLE',''), ('EDUCATION','Masters'), ('EDUCATION','Bachelors'),('EDUCATION','Doctorates/PhD'),('EDUCATION','Associates'),('EDUCATION','None')]
df.columns = pd.MultiIndex.from_tuples(cols)
```